# Find all intersecting polygons in a shape file

Tags: python, gis, qgis, geopandas

I am trying to find out all the polygons in a shapefile through QGIS Algorithm Extract By Location and it gives me perfect results but takes too much time, around 25 hours. Now, I want it to be done by other libraries like geopandas or other libraries if possible. Can anyone suggest me which library can help?

This is what am doing in geopandas:

```
import itertools

import geopandas as gpd

gi = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("D:\Shape_file_uploader\qgis\laneGroup.shp")

geoms = gi['geometry'].tolist()

intersection_iter = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries([poly[0].intersection(poly[1]) for poly in  itertools.combinations(geoms, 2)
```

Comment: geopandas should be your first call to try out

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Please see above code, am I doing it right? I have added it

Comment: I will provide a tentative answer on how to tackle

Comment: Can you explain what Extract By Location is doing?

Comment: Extract By Location gives a shapefile that is a result of the intersection of polygons in the input shapefile. The result is accurate but takes a longer time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating areas of polygons inside other polygons with GeoPandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55131380/calculating-areas-of-polygons-inside-other-polygons-with-geopandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this some time ago and if I remember correctly I used the geopandas overlay method. So the 'pseudo' code to handle this ...

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, overlay

first_shape_gdf = GeoDataFrame.from_file('D:\Shape_file_uploader\qgis\laneGroup.shp')
second_shape_gdf = GeoDataFrame.from_file('another.shp')

intersection_gdf = overlay(first_shape_gdf, second_shape_gdf, how='intersection')
```

Have a look at [Set-Operations with Overlay](http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html)

Comment: I used this earlier. But this is for finding intersecting polygons between two shapefiles. And I need to find the intersecting polygons within the same shapefiles.

Comment: There you have me, I would have no idea how to do this... probably would need to split the shape file first...

Comment: Can you pass the same dataframe twice to overlay function, as both first and second argument?

Comment: @MichaelEntin Yes you can but It does not give you the accurate results as compared to Extract By Location.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen Actually this solves my problem when I pass the same data frame twice. But it gives the partial intersected geometry. But still, It solves my problem. Thanks.